# Сортировка данных DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Провожу сортировку DataTable таким образом

```
        DataGridViewColumn Column = dataGridView4.SortedColumn;
        SortOrder Order = SortOrder.None;
        try
        {
            int Index = Column.Index;
            Order = Column.DataGridView.SortOrder;
            DataView SortView = new DataView();
            if (Info.BasicMethods.ValueInfo.TypeSourceData == "localhost")
            {
                switch (Index)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            //SortOrder.Descending SortOrder.Ascending
                            if (Order == SortOrder.Descending)
                            {
                                SortView = MainForm.ValueInfo.Data.DefaultView;
                                SortView.Sort = "Name DESC";
                                MainForm.ValueInfo.Data = SortView.ToTable();
                            }
                            else if (Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
                            {
                                SortView = MainForm.ValueInfo.Data.DefaultView;
                                SortView.Sort = "Name ASC";
                                MainForm.ValueInfo.Data = SortView.ToTable();
                            }
                            break;
                        }
```

данные сортируются во всех колонках, кроме.

> Кроме колонки содержащей изображения, то есть её последовательность не меняется. (сортировка колонки установлена программно)

Answer (score 1):

Если привязать таблицу к DataGridView, то сортировка у столбца с Image отключена, но если нажать на название другого столбца, то строки сортируются.
Пример:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;    
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

var f = new Form();
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("image", typeof(Image));
// заполняем таблицу тестовыми данными
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, GetBitmap(i) });
// создаем грид и подключаем его к таблице
new DataGridView() {
    Parent = f,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    AllowUserToAddRows = false,
    DataSource = dt
};
f.ShowDialog();

// создает тестовый Image
static Image GetBitmap(int id) {
    var b = new Bitmap(20, 30);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        g.DrawString(id.ToString(), new Font("verdana", 12), Brushes.Red, PointF.Empty);
    return b;
}
```